# OOP - Is it better to call functions from within other functions, or to have one big controller?

Tags: javascript, oop, solid-principles

I'm re-writing a fairly complex script that I created a few weeks ago. After showing it to a few people, they all agreed that I should break it up into smaller pieces (classes) that have a specific purpose, and [SOLID object-oriented programming principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

As a self-taught programmer these concepts are pretty new to me, and I'm a little confused about how to best transfer data from one function/class to another. For instance, here is a simplified structure of what I'm building:

[image]

**MY QUESTION IS:**

Should I have a "controller" script that calls all of these functions/classes and passes the data around wherever necessary? Is this where I would put the `for loop` from the diagram above, even though it would work just as well as part of `Function 1` which could then call `Function 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a controller/service script you'll not be able to meet single responsibility principle in fact. Here's a high level design I'd implement if I were you.

**FileRepository**
Should expose a method to get a file. Let's name it *GetFileById*.

**MongoDBRepository**
Methods for CRUD operations. Such as *SelectById*, *SelectByQuery*, *Update*, *Create*, *Delete*.

**Object creation logic**
If your *createNewObj* logic is simple it would be enough to move it to your object contructor so that your code looks like that:  `var newObj = new MyObj(json[i]);`
But if it's relatively complex maybe because you use some third party frameforks for validation or whatever you'd better create a factory. Then you could would look this way: `var newObj = MyObjFactory.Create(json[i]);`

**Service/controller**
Finally you'll need to implement controller/service object. Let's name it *WorkService* with a method *DoWork* which should handle all interactions between the repositories and other objects discribed above. Here's approximately DoWork should look like:

```
function DoWork(fileId){
  var json = fileRepository.SelectById(fileId);
  for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
     var newObj = new MyObj(json[i]);  // or calling factory method
     var dbRecord = MongoDBRepository.SelectByQuery(newObj.name, newObj.date);
     if(dbRecord){
       MongoDBRepository.Update(newObj);
     }
     else{
       MongoDBRepository.Create(newObj);
     }
  }
}
```

Please note it's just a javascript syntax pseudo-code. Your actual code might look absolutley different but it gives your a feeling of what kind of design your should have. Also I exmplicitly didn't create a repository objects inside *DoWork* method, think of the way to inject them so you meet Dependency inversion principle.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! Just to clarify, if within the `newObj` class I need to call on several functions in order to return the object. Example, `function 1` loads the JSON data, `function 2` prepares an object, `function 3` strips some tags from the text in the object. Is it ok for function 1 to call `function 2`, and `function 2` to call `function 3`? Or do I need a separate controller for this?

Comment: It depends, just think if any of the functions (1,2,3) can be reused anywhere else except for this object creation? If yes then create a special service class for them and a factory class for your object creation logic (second option from "Object creation logic"). Then you can use the new service in the factory class.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. It's little things like this that, as a self-taught programmer, you don't really realise that you don't know. Appreciate the help.